# How to use monad-control for a simple newtype wrapper over ReaderT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have defined a simple monad transformer, `EntityBuilderT`, that is just a newtype over `ReaderT`.

```
data EntityBuilderState = ...

newtype EntityBuilderT m a = EntityBuilderT (ReaderT EntityBuilderState m a)
```

To wrap a function in a new "environment", I have written the following combinator:

```
withNewSource :: (Monad m) => String -> EntityBuilderT m a -> EntityBuilderT m a
withNewSource itemId builder = ...
```

In certain cases, I also want to build a larger transformer stack. For example:

```
f :: MaybeT (EntityBuilderT m) a
```

Obviously, I cannot apply `withNewSource` to this function `f` as the monad types no longer match. I have therefore tried to use `monad-control` to write a new version of such combinator.

The code I've written thus far is shown below. Though the instance definitions seems to be OK, the compiler (GHC 7.4.1) rejects the code with the following message:

```
   Couldn't match type `IO' with `EntityBuilderT m0'
    When using functional dependencies to combine
      MonadBaseControl IO IO,
        arising from the dependency `m -> b'
        in the instance declaration in `Control.Monad.Trans.Control'
      MonadBaseControl (EntityBuilderT m0) IO,
        arising from a use of `control'
    In the expression: control
    In the expression: control $ \ run -> withNewSource itemId (run m)
```

I'm somewhat lost. Anyone understands what the problem really is?

---

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,
             MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Applicative (Applicative)
import Control.Monad (liftM)
import Control.Monad.Base
import Control.Monad.Trans (MonadTrans)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (ReaderT, withReaderT)


data EntityBuilderState

newtype EntityBuilderT m a = EntityBuilderT { unEB :: ReaderT EntityBuilderState m a }
  deriving (Applicative, Functor, Monad, MonadTrans)

instance MonadBase b m => MonadBase b (EntityBuilderT m) where
    liftBase = liftBaseDefault

instance MonadTransControl EntityBuilderT where
    newtype StT EntityBuilderT a = StEB { unStEB :: StT (ReaderT EntityBuilderState) a }
    liftWith f = EntityBuilderT $ liftWith $ \run ->
                   f $ liftM StEB . run . unEB
    restoreT = EntityBuilderT . restoreT . liftM unStEB

instance MonadBaseControl b m => MonadBaseControl b (EntityBuilderT m) where
    newtype StM (EntityBuilderT m) a = StMT { unStMT :: ComposeSt EntityBuilderT m a }
    liftBaseWith = defaultLiftBaseWith StMT
    restoreM     = defaultRestoreM   unStMT


withNewSource :: (Monad m) => String -> EntityBuilderT m a -> EntityBuilderT m a
withNewSource itemId (EntityBuilderT m) = EntityBuilderT (withReaderT undefined m)

withNewSource' :: String -> MaybeT (EntityBuilderT IO) a -> MaybeT (EntityBuilderT IO) a
withNewSource' itemId m = control $ \run -> withNewSource itemId (run m)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, because the base monad is `IO`, `run` has type `MaybeT (EntityBuilderT IO) a -> IO (StM (MaybeT (EntityBuilderT IO) a))`, but you're using its return value as an `EntityBuilderT IO` action. Additionally, the return value of the function you pass to `control` must be in `IO`, not `EntityBuilderT IO`.

This is because your `MonadBaseControl` instance says that you lift things into the base monad of the transformed monad `m`; since the base of `MaybeT (EntityBuilderT IO)` is `IO`, `control` takes a function from `RunInBase (MaybeT (EntityBuilderT IO)) IO` to `IO (StM (MaybeT (EntityBuilderT IO)) a)`.

Unfortunately, I'm not experienced enough with monad-control to suggest a solution; perhaps you could use `MaybeT`'s `MonadTransControl` instance to achieve the "one level down" functionality?

Comment: Your explanation makes a lot of sense. However, the code still fails to typecheck:

Couldn't match type `IO' with `EntityBuilderT m0'
    When using functional dependencies to combine
      MonadBaseControl IO IO,
        arising from the dependency `m -> b'
        in the instance declaration in `Control.Monad.Trans.Control'
      MonadBaseControl (EntityBuilderT m0) IO,
        arising from a use of `control'
    In the expression: control
    In the expression:
      control $ \ run -> withNewSource itemId (liftBase (run m))

Comment: Oops, sorry! I've updated my answer. By the way, you can use [multiple backticks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code) to format code containing backticks.